# Symfony 4 | Accessing a username passed with traditional user form (from doc)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following a tutorial at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html and I would like to have access to username. I want to make the session store the username, but I have no idea how to catch the username of the logged in user.

So far I have tried `$username = $request->get('username');` in SecurityController and next tried to set session 'username' key to `$username` but it doesn't work.

**SecurityController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Adrian
 * Date: 2018-01-29
 * Time: 11:02
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/panel/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils) {
        $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }

}
```

**login.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/panel/dashboard"/>
        {#
            If you want to control the URL the user
            is redirected to on success (more details below)
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
        #}

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Later I would like to access this username like this:

```
$session = $request->getSession();
$username = $session->get('username');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user successfully logs-in, you can get the username in a controller with `$this->getUser()->getUsername()` (whatever your getter looks like).

If the user does not successfully log-in you can create a Doctrine entity and persist failed attempts then call that entity later. It depends on what you want to do with it?

Comment: Certainly. Good luck.